# Image mode conversion from mode I to mode L

Tags: image, image-processing

How to convert 32-bit signed integer pixels to 8-bit pixels, black and white? I have a grayscale image of mode I i.e, 8-bit pixels, black and white so I need to convert to mode L 8-bit pixels, black and white.

Comment: what language, what library?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Python library pillow

```
from PIL import Image

path = "path_to_folder_with_image/my_image.png"

with Image.open(path) as image:
    if image.mode == 'I':
        image = image.convert("L")
```